# Not able install maven in windows

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, maven-3

While trying to install to maven in windows I'm getting this error.

What I have tried is, 
I have set the Environment variables as follows :

System variable :

```
MAVEN_HOME :: C:\Users\hari\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9
```

User Variable ::

```
PATH : C:\Users\HARI\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre
```

ERROR in cmd :

```
C:\Users\hari>mvn -version

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/l
ogging/LoggerManager

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getEnhancedMainMethod(Launcher.java:172)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:268)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.logging.LoggerManager

        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)


        ... 10 more
```

What I should do to configure it rightly?

Comment: Remove the MAVEN_HOME variable. Only put it into PATH veriable...Check also if you have M2_HOME in your environment from a previous installation....if so remove it...

Comment: can you try including the `libexec` in your `MAVEN_HOME` path, i am usinhg mac and its `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec`.

Comment: Java Home should be JAVA_HOME : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`

Comment: Still doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Set M2_HOME = <PATH To Maven>
Set M2=%M2_HOME%\bin
Add M2 to Path variable
PATH = ;%M2%
```

Comment: Please to add more information to your answer instead of copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

you have to set M2_HOME variable. Follow the url http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/